# Criteria in marking questions duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've seen two question that are very much the same (the context of the question, the possible anwers, etc). It is asked five months later than the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8700870/4043409) one. But instead of marking the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11178673/4043409) one as duplicate, it is the first one that has been marked. Why? Is it because the later question has more upvotes that the previous one? And of course **why would it be upvoted more in the first place**? The two questions are identical, if the user searched the web(or StackOverflow) for at least 10 minutes, then he should have found the answer and had not asked... Im just wondering.

---

I'm asking this because basically the questions are both of the same quality (OK, not *really* the same but there are negligible decimal digits), and considering other criteria are factored out, the only thing (in my opinion) that can be the tie-breakers are the popularity (number of views, upvotes, answer, etc.) and the date the question was asked.